# System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID(VisualStudioProgId) return null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte, windows-server-2019

Please help me:

Machine 1: `win2007`(works fine)
Machine 2: `winServer 2019 Datacenter`(Facing issue)
On Both machines: Same C# code is executed on `VS2019` and i want to invoke `VS2017`

C# Code:

```
string VisualStudioProgId = "VisualStudio.DTE." + vsVersion;
Type type = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID(VisualStudioProgId);
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Activator.CreateInstance(type,true);
```

1. The code is working fine on machine 1(win2007)
2. On Machine 2(winServer 2019) - Unhandled Exception is reported:
   [image]

I tried to debug C# code further in VS2019 in both machines
Observed different `type` for `Class System Type`:

**Machine (win2007)(works fine):**
`Class System Type` observed as
`Value: {Name = "__ComObject" FullName = "System.__ComObject"}`
`Type: System.Type {System.RuntimeType}`

[image]

**Machine (winServer 2019)(Facing issue):**
`Class System Type` observed as
`Value: null`
`Type: System.Type`
[image]

Comment: That tells you that VS2017 is not installed on that server.  The normal case.

Comment: @HansPassant, Its Installed  .... "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"  -property catalog_productLineVersion
2019
2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed many more packages after looking in to VS installation in the `machine(win2007)` which is working.
Now `machine with winServer 2019` is also working. But i don´t now which package solved the problem.

**Packages before:**
[image]

**Installed many more packages**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.9.36
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.36+28307.1525
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03761

Installed Version: Community

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.9.04012.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017

ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   15.8.31590
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.61435.0
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.9.03024.0
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

C# Tools   2.10.0-beta2-63501-03+b9fb1610c87cccc8ceb74a770dba261a58e39c4a
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
Simplifying the configuration of Azure DevOps pipelines from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   1.0
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

NuGet Package Manager   4.6.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

ResourcePackage Extension   1.0
ResourcePackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

ResourcePackage Extension   1.0
ResourcePackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.62002.01090
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TcProjectCompare   1.0
Visual Studio Integrated Version of TcProjectCompare

TcXaeDebuggerLiveWatch   1.0
TwinCAT XAE Live Watch Tool Window

TcXaeHelper   1.0
Info

TcXaeModules   1.0
TwinCAT TMC Editor, TwinCAT TMC Code Generator

TcXaeStartPage   1.12
Beckhoff Start Page for TwinCAT XAE

TwinCAT XAE Base   3.1.0.0
The TwinCAT XAE Base extension provides the basic project structure for TwinCAT projects.

TwinCAT XAE EventLogger   1.0
The TwinCAT XAE Eventlogger extension provides the capability of monitoring events sent through the TwinCAT 3 Eventlogger of a target system.

TwinCAT XAE PLC   3.1.0.0
PLC Environment

TypeScript Tools   15.9.30718.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   2.10.0-beta2-63501-03+b9fb1610c87cccc8ceb74a770dba261a58e39c4a
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers
```

Comment: Hi, @ Kumaraswamy Gaviyappa. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.